# Postfix / postqueue flush - MX record flush

Tags: email, postfix-mta

If there are messages in the postfix queue and I want to force the queue delivery via:

> postqueue -f

Will this force a redo of DNS lookup / MX record lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postqueue -f` will flush the queue made of files, that process can be done even after a reboot, and, like an automate, all resolution and contacts steps are done again.

In brief, it repeats the process if name resolution via, first, the MX type entries, and tries (again) to contact the targeted mail servers.

The concern would be more on the DNS side, where the name server may keep a cache of the recently resolved entries. Meaning that even if you change the MX entries (at a registrar in charge of your DN zones for instance), they may seem unchanged from your mail server, depending on the TTL of the DNS server that resolved the MX record.

Comment: postqueue flushes mail but does it flush DNS? I didn't notice any mention of that- and it didn't work for me

Comment: @s29 As mentioned in the answer, the mail domains resolution will be performed again at the time the queue is processed. However, flushing DNS is a different topic. Usually the DNS caching "problem" (just the normal DNS way to cache for TTL) resides at the ISP level (actually where your DNS server/relay is). Of  course, you could force the resolution to be done from the authority servers, or from a new DNS server like Google 8.8.8.8 (if nobody resolved that name before), but other people having to do the MX resolution, without that DNS setting change, will have to wait for the TTL to expire.